# Looking for an elegant way of finding the intersection between two lists of words' tuples in different orders

Tags: python, nlp, tuples, intersection, collocation

I think its best to show an example of what I'm trying to do. The point is that I'm looking for an **elegant way** of doing so.

Let's say I have two lists of tuples:

```
x = [('a', 'c', 'e'), ('k', 'n')]
y = [('e', 'd', 'w'), ('c', 'a', 'e'), ('n', 'k')]
z = set(x).intersection(y)
```

If I compute the intersection between x and y I get an empty set.

My goal is to find out that there are two elements in y that are identical to the two elements in x while I don't care about the different order of the tuples. In addition I want to **get the index of the matching element** of the list y.

For me x[0] and y[1] are the same (again, don't care about the order) and the index I want to get is 1, same for x[1] and y[2] , both are the same for me and it should return the index 2 in this case.

Any ideas on how to do this in an elegant way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can't you make your `x` and `y` `set`s?
E.g.:

```
x = [('a', 'c', 'e'), ('k', 'n')]
y = [('e', 'd', 'w'), ('c', 'a', 'e'), ('n', 'k')]
set_x = set(frozenset(a) for a in x)
set_y = [frozenset(a) for a in y]
[y_element in set_x for y_element in set_y]
```

returns: `[False, True, True]`

If you want the actual indices:

```
[i for i, y_element in enumerate(set_y) if y_element in set_x]
```

returns: `[1, 2]`

Comment: I think he wanted the indexes in y, so enumerate? Would also allow making set_x a set of frozensets.

Comment: Use frozensets instead. Make set_x a set instead of a list.

Comment: In that case, you could just switch the roles of `set_x` and `set_y` to get `[set_y.index(x_element) for x_element in set_x if x_element in set_y]` which will return `[1, 2]`.

Comment: Why do an O(n) `index` on the list for each match, when you can just `enumerate`?